# TinyUmbrella can't find shsh for iOS5

Tags: jailbreak, ios

Before iOS5, we were recommended to save our iPhone's shsh so that when a jb came out, we could restore it back a jb-ed version.

For iOS5, Tiny Umbrella couldn't find any shsh.

So, is there anything we should do while waiting for iOS5's untethered jb?

Comment: Not really. Use your device? SHSH blobs have changed in iOS 5 and will most likely no longer be of use.

Comment: Source? (8 more to go...)

Comment: @VxJasonxV http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/6952986620/blob-monster

Comment: @cksum should really have added this as an answer!